# How to run HTML Tidy so that it fixes the issues in HTML that makes it non-well-formed, not just report issues?

Tags: htmltidy

I have HTML that was generated from a formatted Outlook email message.

I want to convert the HTML to XHTML.

I ran HTML Tidy using the -asxhtml (convert HTML to well-formed XHTML) option.

HTML reported many errors, including:

```
line 1 column 320 - Info: value for attribute "name" missing quote marks
line 39 column 42 - Info: value for attribute "lang" missing quote marks
```

Isn't the purpose of HTML Tidy to fix such things?

Question: how to run HTML Tidy so that it fixes the issues in HTML that makes it non-well-formed, not just report the issues?

Comment: Some things can't be robotically fixed. Some times it requires a human to remediate  some errors.

Also have to tried the -q flag?

Comment: The -q option just hides the error messages but doesn't fix the non-well-formedness issues.